# How to estimate points to award in tiles collecting games

Tags: probability

I am working on a board game where players need to collect set of tiles of the same color.
I need to estimate how many points i need to give as a prize for sets of different dimensions.

Since, for instance, collecting 6 tiles of the same color is more difficult than collecting 2 tiles of the same color, i need to give to the bigger set more points, but how many more? Of course i need the ratio of points between the different sizes.

In random games (like coin tossing) i tend to think that if you manage to achieve something that has a probability N times higher of happening you must get N times less points: for instance , if throwing 4 coins i get 4 heads and you get 2 heads and 2 tails, I will get 6 points and you will get 1 because there is one way to get 4 heads but there are 6 ways to get 2 heads and 2 tails.

In a game like mine players are actually doing something to get set of tiles of the same color and i wonder if my reasoning is still correct:
I have 120 tiles, 42 blue, 42 red, 36 green. Using the hypergeometric multivariate distribution i calculated that there is a 32.9% chance of extracting randomly 2 tiles and get them of the same color (R or G or B); if i extract 4 tiles the prob. is 3.4%, with 6 tiles it's 0.34% and so on. 
This would tell me to give approximately 100 times more points to those who collect 6 tiles of the same color than to those who collect 2 tiles of the same color. But the general impression when i am playing is that it is not that more difficult to collect 6 tiles than to collect 2.

Notice that the color are almost distributed 1/3,1/3,1/3 and one reasoning that comes to my mind is: 
i already have 4 tiles with the same color and i am entitled to P points. If i want to add another tile of this color that i already have, i will have to find one of the same color and i have a probability of 1/3 that the next tile that i find is of the right color, so i deserve to triple my points. The number i get confirm this because passing from 2 to 6 tiles i should have an increase of 3*3*3*3 times that is roughly 100.

Is there a (better) way to estimate the scores i need to give in a mathematically correct way?

Comment: Side note: Take that huge paragraph and split it into well-separated lines, each of which containing a single sentence (if you're actually expecting any one to read all this).